# How to read Json object in spring mvc controller

Tags: json, ajax, spring-mvc

What is the most elegant way to read JSON objects in spring mvc when you have only 1 parameter.

When I have many I create an object that will read the post request sent by ajax but in this case, given the fact I am only sending the username parameter, it seems very ugly.

```
var dataObject = JSON.stringify({
    'username' : 'quentin'
});

$.ajax({
    url : ctx + '/users/edit',
    type : 'POST',
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    },
    data : dataObject
});
```

An attempt is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUser(@RequestBody String username) {

    System.out.println(username);
    return "users/edit";
}
```

This is obviously wrong and gives the below as result

```
%7B%22username%22%3A%22quentin%22%7D=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your **content-type** Try one of the two.

```
$.ajax({
        url :'/users/edit',
        type : 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json", //either
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
         //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); //or
        },
        data : dataObject,
        success: function(data) {

        }  
});
```

Before

```
%7B%22username%22%3A%22quentin%22%7D=
```

After

```
{"username":"quentin"}
```